# java 8 write utf-8 encoding gibberish

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm trying to get a working utf-8 textfile.
By working I mean that it should look correctly in firefox and libreoffice.

To write I use:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(savepath, "UTF-8");
```

For reading with java I use:

```
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(loadpath), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

When reading in again and showing in java it is correct.

With libreoffice or firefox(encoding set to unicode) it shows "gibberish" characters.

Sample text:

```
C'est vrai   (Java) The french "That's true" is shown correct

Cest vrai  (firefox -set to unicode) the "'" becomes a square with "0092" inside
```

EDIT:

```
CÂ’est vrai (firefox -set to middle european (windows) encoding)
```

EDIT2 :

```
writer.println("Cest vrai");
writer.flush();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJBXC.jpg

EDIT 3:
Ok I tried it now with

```
writer.println("C"+"\u0092"+" est vrai");
writer.flush();
```

This leads to (firefox set to unicode):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/izVC5.jpg

In libreoffice calc import it looks even a little diferent (square is empty):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6LrW.jpg

Comment: How are you telling Firefox that the file is in UTF-8?

Comment: 0092 is the comma-like apostrophe in Windows-1252, MS Latin-1 as in French Windows. As the code is correct, somewhere else there happens to be a conversion, probably to your default platform encoding. MS Latin-1 also happens to be the default encoding in HTTP, for HTML.

Comment: To show the encoding in firefox I go to  view-> textencoding.Libreoffice Calc opens with asking for the encoding(already automatically set to utf8) but it shows the gibberish despite correct utf-8 setting

Comment: "Firefox with middle european (windows) encoding" Well... that's not UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, just to show the difference to unicode (from example 2)

Comment: How do you get the string you write *into* your Java program? Is it a String literal? If so, how do you compile your Java code? Try using Unicode escapes in your String (`\u0092`).

Comment: I get the same with that,look at my EDIT3.I got the string from a file, but as you can see (edit3) even with \u0092 it is shown as "gibberish" in firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen in a not so evident trap. U+0092 is not a valid Unicode character. Windows 1252 is *close* to Latin1 but adds some characters. For example the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`’`) is U+2019 but is mapped to `'\x92'` in Windows 1252 charset, and is not available at all in true Latin1.

If you want to write it correctly in Java, you should use `"C\u2019est vrai"`.

That means that the encoding operations are correct, but that the unicode character is wrong. And Firefox is correct in displaying it 0092 in a square as a non existent unicode character.

---

After some more research, I can tell that the characters with code between 0x80 and 0x9f are *dangerous*. 0x81, 0x8d, 0x8f, 0x90, and 0x9d are not mapped at all in Windows 1252 charset, all others are mapped to Unicode characters above 256. Below is a list giving the code in Windows 1252 charset, the corresponding unicode value, the character and its name (thanks to the Python unicodedata module)

```
Different € 0x20ac 0x80 EURO SIGN
Not mapped 0x81
Different ‚ 0x201a 0x82 SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
Different ƒ 0x192 0x83 LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK
Different „ 0x201e 0x84 DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
Different … 0x2026 0x85 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
Different † 0x2020 0x86 DAGGER
Different ‡ 0x2021 0x87 DOUBLE DAGGER
Different ˆ 0x2c6 0x88 MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
Different ‰ 0x2030 0x89 PER MILLE SIGN
Different Š 0x160 0x8a LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON
Different ‹ 0x2039 0x8b SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
Different Œ 0x152 0x8c LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE
Not mapped 0x8d
Different Ž 0x17d 0x8e LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON
Not mapped 0x8f
Not mapped 0x90
Different ‘ 0x2018 0x91 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
Different ’ 0x2019 0x92 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
Different “ 0x201c 0x93 LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
Different ” 0x201d 0x94 RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
Different • 0x2022 0x95 BULLET
Different – 0x2013 0x96 EN DASH
Different — 0x2014 0x97 EM DASH
Different ˜ 0x2dc 0x98 SMALL TILDE
Different ™ 0x2122 0x99 TRADE MARK SIGN
Different š 0x161 0x9a LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON
Different › 0x203a 0x9b SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
Different œ 0x153 0x9c LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE
Not mapped 0x9d
Different ž 0x17e 0x9e LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON
Different Ÿ 0x178 0x9f LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
```

Comment: How do I convert not valid Unicode characters automatically , ( which are shown correctly in javafx, when importing as utf8) ,so that I can safely write them as a utf8 file?

Comment: @user3776738: see my edit for a detailed list of all *special* win 1252 characters.